# Nested models in django

Tags: python, django, nested

I have an django app with a model called Folder, user can create a Folder with a name field. what i want is to make this Folder model nested, so that user will be able to create Folders inside a folder.
For example user created a folder called ABC and got inside the DetailView of that folder and created another folder DEF and then got into DEF and created another folder called GHI and so on.

I am pretty new to django, i tied searching the web but got nothing.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

# The Folders Model.

class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

**views.py**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from ahmed_drive.models import Folder
from . import models
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, CreateView, DeleteView
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect

#### Normal Pages Related Views ####

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "ahmed_drive/home.html"


#### Pages Related Folder Model ####

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")    
class FolderCreate(CreateView):
    model = Folder
    fields = ["name"]
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.save()

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch") 
class FolderListView(ListView):
    model = Folder
    def get_queryset(self):
        si = self.request.GET.get("si")
        if si == None:
            si = ""
        folderList = Folder.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = si)).order_by("-id");
        return folderList
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch") 
class FolderDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Folder
```

Comment: visit django-mptt documentation i thinks it will help you. https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of doing this is using self-relational `ForeignKey`.

```py
# The Folders Model.

class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

If you want more advanced nested set usage, you can check **[django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**.